# Can I direct an edge to the midpoint of another edge in a graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've been trying to make graphs in which I can direct an edge to the midpoint of another edge, as in the following figure:

[image]

So far, what I've tried, (far from ideal, especially with bigger networks), is to create an additional node, and give coordinates to the vertex:

```
G = Graph[{a -> b, c -> d}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0}}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

So, I would like to avoid specifying an extra set of nodes and their coordinates, and instead be able to join "edge to edge". Is this possible?

Thanks!

Pedro

Comment: how would you specify the edge `c -> d` if you do not include `d` in the vertex list?

Comment: That's the question. I think your answer below is a possible solution, but would still require specifying the coordinates of the vertex set. Maybe I can have two "types" of vertex, and just make those "midpoint" vertex all disappear. However, this would distort the edges that I care most about (for instance, the edge from a to b would not be "Straight" but probably will have the intermediate "kink" -if coordinates are unspecified-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can get around adding invisible nodes, but here is a solution that doesn't require manually specifying any coordinates.

The function `edgeToMidpoint` takes as arguments a graph, a source vertex, which may or may not be an existing vertex in the graph, and a target edge.

```
edgeToMidpoint[graph_, sourcevert_, targetedge_] := 
  Module[{g = graph, coords, coord1, coord2, midpoint, mid, 
    newc, newcoords, vertshape, m, x, b, y},
   coords = AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates][[1, 2]];
   coord1 = coords[[Position[VertexList[g], targetedge[[1]]][[1, 1]]]];
   coord2 = coords[[Position[VertexList[g], targetedge[[2]]][[1, 1]]]];
   midpoint = {Mean[{coord1[[1]], coord2[[1]]}], 
     Mean[{coord1[[2]], coord2[[2]]}]};

   If[FreeQ[VertexList[graph], sourcevert],
    {
     slope = -1/FindFit[{coord1, coord2}, m x + b, {m, b}, x][[1, 2]];
     int = midpoint[[2]] - slope midpoint[[1]];
     newc = Nearest[
        {x, y} /. Reverse[Solve[{EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, midpoint] == 0.5, y == slope x + int}, {x, y}]],
        Mean[coords],
        DistanceFunction -> (-Norm[#1 - #2] &)][[1]];
     newcoords = {newc, midpoint}
     },
    newcoords = {midpoint}];

   vertshape = 
    If[Length[AbsoluteOptions[graph, VertexShapeFunction][[1, 2]]] == 0,
     {_ -> Automatic, mid -> None},
     Append[AbsoluteOptions[graph, VertexShapeFunction][[1, 2]], mid -> None]];

   Graph[
     Join[EdgeList[graph], {sourcevert \[DirectedEdge] mid}],
     VertexCoordinates -> Join[coords, newcoords],
     VertexLabels -> 
      Append[AbsoluteOptions[graph, VertexLabels][[1, 2]], mid -> None],
     VertexShapeFunction -> vertshape,
     ImagePadding -> 10]
   ];
```

The example from the OP:

```
g = Graph[{a \[DirectedEdge] b}, VertexLabels -> "Name"];
edgeToMidpoint[g, c, a \[DirectedEdge] b]
```

[image]

With a slightly more complicated example:

```
g = Graph[{a -> b, d -> b, b -> c, c -> d}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  VertexShapeFunction -> Automatic, ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image]

Calling `edgeToMidpoint` iteratively to add multiple new vertices-to-edges:

```
modlist = {{w, d \[DirectedEdge] b}, {x, c \[DirectedEdge] d}, {z, a \[DirectedEdge] b}, {c, d \[DirectedEdge] b}};
h = g;
Do[h = edgeToMidpoint[h, mod[[1]], mod[[2]]], {mod, modlist}]
h
```

[image]

The placement of new vertices is probably not super robust, but it works for these simple examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can  make the extra vertices invisible using `VertexLabels -> None` and `VertexShapeFunction -> None`:

```
Graph[{a -> b, c -> d}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0}}, 
  VertexLabels -> {_ -> "Name", d -> None}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> {_ -> Automatic, d -> None}]
```

[image]

You get the same result using

```
Graph[{a, b, c, Property[d, {VertexLabels -> None, VertexShapeFunction -> None}]}, 
  {a -> b, c -> d}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {2, 0}, {1.5, 0.5}, {1.5, 0}}, 
  VertexLabels ->  "Name"]
```

> same picture

You can avoid specifying the coordinates of the invisible vertex `d` using `RegionNearest`:

```
 Graph[{a -> b, c -> d}, 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{1, 0}, {2, .25}, {1.5, 0.5}, 
   RegionNearest[Line[{{1, 0}, {2, .25}}], {1.5, .5}]}, 
  VertexLabels -> {_ -> "Name", d -> None}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> {_ -> Automatic, d -> None}]
```

[image]

With random coordinates for the first three vertices:

```
SeedRandom[777]
vc = RotateRight @ SortBy[First] @ RandomReal[1, {3, 2}];
Graph[{a -> b, c -> d}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> Append[vc, RegionNearest[Line[vc[[;;2]]], vc[[3]]]], 
 VertexLabels -> {_ -> "Name", d -> None},
 VertexShapeFunction -> {_ -> Automatic, d -> None}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Using the option `EdgeShapeFunction` to redirect the edge `c -> a` to the nearest point on the edge `a -> b`:

```
g1 = Graph[{a -> b, c -> a},  GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", ImageSize -> 300];
g2 = SetProperty[{g1, c \[DirectedEdge] a},
  EdgeShapeFunction -> (Arrow[{#[[1]], 
    RegionNearest[Line[PropertyValue[{g1, #}, VertexCoordinates]&/@ {a, b}], #[[1]]]}] &)];

Row[{g1, g2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]